# What is the essence of the Row Reduction Algorithm?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some questions about Row Reduction Algorithm

Frist question: **What is the significance of the oder of variables in a linear equation?**
For example:

$
0+\color{red}{3x_2}-\color{blue}{6x_3}+\color{blue}{6x_4}+6x_5=-5\\
\color{red}{3x_1}-\color{red}{7x_2}+\color{blue}{8x_3}-\color{blue}{5x_4}+8x_5=9\\
\color{red}{3x_1}-\color{red}{9x_2}+\color{blue}{12x_3}-\color{blue}{9x_4}+6x_5=15
$

There is a linear equation group, and I think it is equivalent to:
$
-\color{blue}{6x_3}+\color{blue}{6x_4}+ 0+\color{red}{3x_2}+6x_5=-5\\
\color{blue}{8x_3}-\color{blue}{5x_4} + \color{red}{3x_1}-\color{red}{7x_2}+8x_5=9\\
\color{blue}{12x_3}-\color{blue}{9x_4}+ \color{red}{3x_1}-\color{red}{9x_2}+6x_5=15
$

These two linear equation groups can be recorded in two different Matrix

Terms and entries with respect to the coefficient $x_1$ and $x_2$ marked as $\color{red}{red}$, and with respect to the coefficient $x_3$ and $x_4$ marked as $\color{blue}{blue}$

\begin{bmatrix} 
\color{red}0 & \color{red}3 & \color{blue}{-6} & \color{blue}{6} & 4 & -5 \\ 
\color{red}3 & \color{red}{-7} & \color{blue}{8} & \color{blue}{-5} & 8 & 9 \\ 
\color{red}3 & \color{red}{-9} & \color{blue}{12} & \color{blue}{-9} & 6 & 15 
\end{bmatrix}

and

\begin{bmatrix} 
\color{blue}{-6} & \color{blue}{6} & \color{red}0 & \color{red}3 & 4 & -5 \\ 
\color{blue}{8} & \color{blue}{-5} &\color{red}3 & \color{red}{-7} & 8 & 9 \\ 
\color{blue}{12} & \color{blue}{-9}&\color{red}3 & \color{red}{-9} & 6 & 15 
\end{bmatrix}

And their reduced echelon form is：

\begin{bmatrix} 
\color{red}1 & 0 & \color{blue}{-2} & \color{blue}3 & 0 & -24 \\ 
0 & \color{red}1 & \color{blue}{-2} & \color{blue}2 & 0 & -7 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}

and

\begin{bmatrix} 
\color{blue}1 & 0 & \color{red}{-\frac{3}{2}} & \color{red}1 & 0 & -\frac{27}{2} \\ 
0 & \color{blue}1 & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}1 & 0 & -17 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}

And their solution set is:
$$ \left\{
\begin{aligned}
\color{red}{x_1} & = 2x_3-3x_4-24 \\
\color{red}{x_2} & = 2x_3-2x_4-7 \\
\color{blue}{x_3} & \ is\ free\ variable \\
\color{blue}{x_4}& \ is\ free\ variable \\
x_5 & = 4
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

and

$$ \left\{
\begin{aligned}
\color{blue}{x_3} & = \frac{3}{2}x_1-x_2-\frac{27}{2} \\
\color{blue}{x_4} & = x_1-x_2-7 \\
\color{red}{x_1} & \ is\ free\ variable \\
\color{red}{x_2} & \ is\ free\ variable \\
x_5 & = 4
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
So why two equivalent systems of equations have different solution sets after being recorded in matrices? Is this caused by a change in the order of variables?

And I want to use this example to raise my second question, **What is the significance of pivots in a Matrix?** Why choose piovts as the basic variables? And why always choose the leftmost term as pivot?

So What is the essence of the Row Reduction Algorithm?

Comment: Matrix form *assumes* all entries in a column go with a single variable. Also it is up to the user to keep track of which variable goes with which column, so that interpretation of reduced form is right.

Comment: Thank you, I find the mistake. I will edit my question as soon as possible.

Comment: It looks to me like your second rref'd matrix has the third and fourth columns switched from what they should be.

Comment: Yes, and I just don't konw, how the oder of variabiles  influence the matrix and why should we use row reduction operarion to determine pivot position. What is the special significance of pivot postion?